# ng-repeat with http.get not updating

Tags: angularjs, http-get

I have a simple `http.get` call in my controller as below

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.displayBean = {};
$scope.fetchEventDetails = function() {
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/event_details?eventId=' + $scope.data.selectedEventId)
    .then(function(theEvent){
      $scope.data.displayBean = theEvent;
  });
};
```

And in my view I have used `ng-repeat` like below

```
<div class="list-group" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(key,val) in data.displayBean">
  <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">{{key}}</h5>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">{{val}}</p>
</a>
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to update the view even though I get the reponse from the API call when I log it to the console.

Anything I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.displayBean = {};
$scope.fetchEventDetails = function() {
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/event_details?eventId=' + $scope.data.selectedEventId)
    .then(function(theEvent){
      $scope.data.displayBean = theEvent.data;
  });
}
```

can you try $scope.data.displayBean = theEvent.data;

Comment: Already tried that. When I log that value on the console, I get the response from the server. But it just doesnt get rendered in the ng-repeat on the view

Comment: @SaifAsif, Ok friend ,I didnt see anything else as an issue from your code.Thank you